# Showing referencing items in list view

Tags: list-view, lookup-column

I need to create a list view in SharePoint where several foreign Items which are referencing the the actual item are beeing displayed.

As example the actual list is called companies and for each company several or all employees should be displayed.

I've created a custom view in SharePoint Designer 2010 using the "Preview Pane" as design which already comes quit close to my preferred layout.

But how can I add the items (employees), which are referencing the company? I've looked into the source of the page and saw a lot of xml and xlst which gave me somehow the idea of doing this. However I would like to have some best practices on querying referencing items. Do I need to somehow join the lists?

Including the html for displaying seems like an easy go, but I don't now how to get the data to display! Thanks for any information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a list view, or an item view?

**List View**: you can create any web part page and add a list view web part to that page, listing all items of the company list. Now you can do the same with your employee list. After both list view web parts have been added to the page, you can connect them by using the web part properties.

**Item View**: in SharePoint 2010 you can modify the display forms of list items. You can find the link in the ribbon when you're in your company list. Once you're in the edit mode, you can insert "related lists" and insert a filtered employee list right in your display form of the company.

If you need more layout options, you can modify your views in SharPoint Designer